# How can I group variables by several criteria in a data frame to count the number of values greater than each grouped mean?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to count data on a big data frame. First I estimated means by group, and I 've calculated means for each group of each variable. I
you want to count the occurrences of values in each group that are greater than their respective group means.

I have a data frame simmilar to this:

```
stage   sex cort    granu   
a   m   0.53    50
a   m   0.65    93
a   f   3.18    49
a   m   1.51    45
a   m   0.28    57
a   f   0.50    36
a   f   1.20    21
a   f   2.36    58
b   m   0.27    74
b   m   0.16    36
b   f   0.42    27
b   m   0.88    65
b   f   2.19    85
b   m   0.24    74
b   f   0.89    52
b   m   0.34    98
b   f   2.59    52
b   f   0.74    63
c   m   6.36    54
c   f   2.07    24
c   m   1.46    12
c   m   2.07    36
c   f   1.46    75
c   m   2.19    96
c   f   6.36    21
c   f   2.19    85
```

I would like to count the number of values that are greater than the mean of the group, to the moment I did something like this

```
mean_c<- aggregate(x= data$cort,
                       by = list(data$sex,data$stage),      
                       FUN = mean)

cah<-dplyr::filter(data,stage=="a" & sex=="h")
cah<-dplyr::select(cah, c(cort))
countah<-corta>1.81 #mean for the group (a,h)

cam<-dplyr::filter(data,stage=="a" & sex=="m")
cam<-dplyr::select(cam, c(cort))
countam<-corta>0.74 #mean for the group (a,m)

sum(countah)
```

But, I need to do the same with several variables in all the stages (a,b and c) and with both sexes (f,m). I can repeat the last four lines with each mean, but I think there may be an easier and less redundant way to do this but I can't think of any.

Comment: Just responding to your comment on my answer as it is still not clear what your desired output is. Could you please include an example of your desired output? Doing so makes answering questions much easier. Once you have, I will update my answer where necessary .Also, there are some issues with your code 1) There is no "h" value in data$sex, I think you mean "f"? 2) you refer to an object/variable called "corta" but your code does not create it. Also, I see you have updated your sample data. Note that I have edited my answer so that it uses your new data. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions `group_by()` and `summarise()` are what you need:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- read.table(text = "stage   sex cort    granu   
a   m   0.53    50
a   m   0.65    93
a   f   3.18    49
a   m   1.51    45
a   m   0.28    57
a   f   0.50    36
a   f   1.20    21
a   f   2.36    58
b   m   0.27    74
b   m   0.16    36
b   f   0.42    27
b   m   0.88    65
b   f   2.19    85
b   m   0.24    74
b   f   0.89    52
b   m   0.34    98
b   f   2.59    52
b   f   0.74    63
c   m   6.36    54
c   f   2.07    24
c   m   1.46    12
c   m   2.07    36
c   f   1.46    75
c   m   2.19    96
c   f   6.36    21
c   f   2.19    85", header = TRUE, check.names = FALSE)

df1 <- df %>%
  group_by(stage, sex) %>%
  summarise(sum_gt_mean = sum(cort > mean(cort)), .groups = "drop")

df1
# A tibble: 6 × 3
stage    sex    sum_gt_mean
<chr>   <chr>     <int>
1 a       f         2
2 a       m         1
3 b       f         2
4 b       m         1
5 c       f         1
6 c       m         1
```

Comment: It seems that my question was not clear enough... so, I could apply part of the solution. I edited the question